# Docker for Windows - failed to mount local volume, no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the same problem like here [Docker - failed to mount local volume, no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671155/docker-failed-to-mount-local-volume-no-such-file-or-directory)

```bash
docker-compose --verbose up -d
[+] Running 0/0
 - Container brickchart-mysql-1  Creating                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount 
.docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/brickchart_db_volume/_data, 
flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      MYSQL_USER: db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql:delegated

volumes:
  db_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: ./.docker/mysql/data
```

I have the latest Docker Desktop installed:

[image]

I also tested older versions: 4.14.0, 4.12.0 and 4.10.1.

I understand that the docker-compose file is converted to docker commands. A verbose flag would help a lot. Unfortunately, it seems like the verbose flag doesn't exist:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1640

It would be great if I can see how

```yaml
volumes:
  - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
```

will be converted in to docker commands.

Does anybody have any tips for this problem?

Comment: Does `./.docker/mysql/data` exists on the host?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The relative path './.docker/mysql/data' should be created. That used to work before.

Answer (score 0):

This [Volume binding using docker compose on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334021/volume-binding-using-docker-compose-on-windows) helps me to solve my problem.

It must be an absolute path to the host system.

So my solution is right now.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      MYSQL_USER: db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql:delegated

volumes:
  db_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: ${PATH_TO_DB_DATA}
```

The corresponding .env contains the variable PATH_TO_DB_DATA.
Example:

```bash
PATH_TO_DB_DATA='/d/path/to/my-project/.docker/mysql/data/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still struggling with this. I'm running Docker from WSL2. Here's an example of a docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    hostname: db
    image: postgres:11.5
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./deploy/pgsql/certs:/var/lib/postgresql/certs:ro
volumes:
  database:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: ${POSTGRES_DATA_DIR:-./postgres-data}
```

My .env file looks like this.

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=label-studio
POSTGRES_DATA_DIR=/home/ehansen/label-studio/database
```

This results in the following error. Note that I removed some services that aren't relevant from the examples above.

```
(dev) ehansen@BIGBOSS:~/repos/configs/label-studio$ docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 2/3
 ⠿ Container label-studio-db-1     Starting                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s 
 ✔ Container label-studio-app-1    Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 ✔ Container label-studio-nginx-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/label-studio_database/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/b43b9941a24aea00254d1fad5f6ec9d795b4bde303ed33175b927834a858317e:/var/lib/docker/volumes/label-studio_database/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
(dev) ehansen@BIGBOSS:~/repos/configs/label-studio$
```