# volume failing in docker but not docker-compose

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, docker-desktop

When starting my docker container, I run this command:

```
docker run -d \
  --name metadata-service00 \
  -p 8080:8084 \
  -v ./FilesToReplace/LogBack/logback.xml:/app/conf/logback.xml \
  [docker image]:build-897
```

it works flawlessly.

However, when I run the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  activemq:
    image: [image 2]]:build-31
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "1883:1883"
    networks:
      - activemq_metadata_network
  metadata-service:
    image: [image 1]]:build-897
    container_name: metadata-service00
    ports:
      - "8080:8084"
    volumes:
      - ./FilesToReplace/LogBack/logback.xml:/app/conf/logback.xml


networks:
  activemq_metadata_network:
    driver: bridge
```

I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/untitledfolder3_config_volume/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /host_mnt/Users/[user name]/Desktop/untitled folder 3/FilesToReplace/LogBack/logback.xml:/var/lib/docker/volumes/untitledfolder3_config_volume/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
```

I've attempted running the docker command (as stated above), as well as:

- using a non-relative path
- using `$(pwd)` instead of `./`
- restarting my Macbook

p.s.
both the docker-compose and FilesToReplace exists in the same directory (that exists in desktop), the docker cli was run from within that directory.

(my last post got closed even tho I see many posts about docker I'm really not sure what I did wrong)

Comment: this most likely got closed cause it's almost 100% a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671155/docker-failed-to-mount-local-volume-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Try mounting the folder, not a file. I recall error that compose cannot mount files, and will always do folders, so it's saying `/app/conf/logback.xml` doesn't exist, even if `/app/conf/` does

Comment: that worked, but now another file in the host machine is being deleted. (another file in the same directory)

if its not solvable, I can just put that file in the local directory too, but I'd prefer just keeping it in the machine if possible

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77620960/volume-failing-in-docker-but-not-docker-compose - why did you delete that and repost the same question?

Comment: Why are you trying to mount a relative path? As soon as the task is given to the docker daemon it may apply the path as seen from it's current working directory - not yours.